# Set execution timeout limit while creating docker

Tags: php, testing, jenkins, docker

We are getting an "Error Message - Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded" on every Test through Jenkin.

Using jenkin we are creating new docker image on every test.

We changed the php max execution settings to unlimited. But it is not reflecting in the jenkin.

How do we change the setting while creating docker?